# Installing CUDA-8 .deb file on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, apt, nvidia, cuda

I downloaded the Cuda toolkit from Site.
I placed the file in Home location
"**root@harish-pc:/home/harish# ls
esktop                    Documents                                                  Downloads        Music       Videos
NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-375.39.run
Pictures
cuda-repo-ubuntu1404-8-0-local-ga2_8.0.61-1_amd64.deb  Links for RNN-Nvidia  Public
root@harish-pc:/home/harish# "**
I tried following the installation documentation for Ubuntu.
I got struck up at the command

```
sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-<distro>_<version>_<architecture>.deb
```

The error displayed is no such file or repo (distro).

Then I gave full permissions to file and tried again .
This time the error displayed is

```
harish@harish-pc:~$ bash cuda-repo-ubuntu1404-8-0-local-ga2_8.0.61-1_amd64.deb
cuda-repo-ubuntu1404-8-0-local-ga2_8.0.61-1_amd64.deb: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
cuda-repo-ubuntu1404-8-0-local-ga2_8.0.61-1_amd64.deb: line 1: `!<arch>'
```

I have correctly placed the downloaded file in Home Location.
Should i need to install Cuda from Command line or tty terminal ?

Do I need to install Cuda supported Tensorflow on my system ?

My system configs is:

```
Ubuntu 14.04
Nvidia Geforce 830M
latest Driver: Nvidia 375.39(Defaulted by Additional Tools)
```

Comment: Where did you put the downloaded `.deb` file? `cd` into that directory. do a `ls`. add the output to your question.

Comment: seems to me the command: `sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1404-8-0-local-ga2_8.0.61-1_amd64.deb`, should work for you.

Comment: harish@harish-pc:~$ sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1404-8-0-local-ga2_8.0.61-1_amd64.deb

Selecting previously unselected package cuda-repo-ubuntu1404-8-0-local-ga2.
(Reading database ... 238020 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack cuda-repo-ubuntu1404-8-0-local-ga2_8.0.61-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cuda-repo-ubuntu1404-8-0-local-ga2 (8.0.61-1) ...
Setting up cuda-repo-ubuntu1404-8-0-local-ga2 (8.0.61-1) ...
OK

harish@harish-pc:~$

Comment: i got this in terminal

Comment: Do i need to perform "sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1404-8-0-local-ga2_8.0.61-1_amd64.deb" as root ....."root@harish-pc:/home/harish# "
or 
 Do i need to do it from tty screen
or
Do i need to do it from User ----"harish@harish-pc:~$ "

Comment: What if i do it in both "harish@harish-pc:~$"  ----------User
and in root "root@harish-pc:/home/harish# "----------Root

Comment: Seems installed to me.